# Undetermined Coefficients Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$Y'''+4y'=t$$
My attempt: For t I took my guess to be in the form $y_p= At+B$, however, this method fails to give the correct answer, is it because 'y' is missing from the original ODE? Annihilator method works though to give the correct answer

Comment: You can define $x = y'$ so that your equation becomes $x''+4x = t$.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, whatever method you use annihilator or else

$$Y'''+4y'=t \implies r^3+4r=0 \implies r(r^2+4)=0 \implies r=0,-2i,2i$$
$$y_h=c_1+c_2\cos(2x)+c_3\sin(2x)$$
Try $y_p=at^2+bt+c $ instead of $y_p=at+b$
$$\implies 4(2at+b)=t  \implies a=\frac18 \,; b=0 $$
$$\implies y_p=\frac {t^2}8+c$$
Therefore
$$y(x)=c_1+c_2\cos(2x)+c_3\sin(2x)+\frac {t^2}8$$

---

Or you can integrate the equation directly
$$y'''+4y'=t $$
$$y''+4y=\frac {t^2}2+K$$
And apply the variation of constant...